# Android: can not load local library module dependency for test: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, junit

We have an 3rd party local native module dependency in our project: `opencv_java3`.
Now, we want do add test, but we face the situation in which the test can not access the module.
According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies) the scope should be implementation*, following this our (relevant) dependencies looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':openCVLibrary310')
    api "org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:${var}"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.2.0'
}
```

Our settings.gradle contains only the following entry:

```
include ':app', ':openCVLibrary310'
```

Now when testing a class, which uses the openCVLibrary310 dependency we face the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java3 in java.library.path

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
...
```

thrown when the library is loaded at:

```
System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");
```

Thanks for any advice's

* implementation: Most app and test modules should use this configuration.

Comment: PS. I'm perfectly aware that any usage of third party library should not be tested within a unit test of our own code, but because of reasons, mocking is not easy (possible) here.

Comment: Did you ever managed to do this? I have the same problem